# I have a WebView that is loading a page from the Internet (Suppose url is https://example.org/wiki/). But url redirect to home page of the website

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView that is loading a page from the Internet (Suppose url is https://example.org/wiki/). But url redirect to home page of the website.uppose url is https://example.org/home/)

Comment: Hi, are you able to load https://example.org/wiki/ in a android browser?

Comment: No. When I can not load it directly to the browser. When i paste url into the browser it redirect to home page.But if i click wiki tab then example.org/wiki (it is symbolic website) is opening. plz help what can i do?

Comment: You will have to use javascript for loading correct url

Comment: I already solved it by JavaScript. But i cannot apply it in the webview. I try to access html class and apply click() function on it.likw var home=document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-home')[0];home.click(). But how i write it in the webview.

Comment: public void page1(View view)
    {
        webView.loadUrl(
                "javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var home=document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-home')[0];" +
                        "home.click();" +
                        "})()");
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via Javascript like this:

Either you can override `onProgressChange` in `ChromeClient` like this:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress){
                if(newProgress > 50){
                    view.evaluateJavascript("your JS", null);
                }
            }
        });
```

Or you can override anyone of the methods in `WebViewClient` to execute your javascript at appropriate time. Example: you can use `onPageFinished`, `onPageStarted`, or `onLoadResource` as per your needs to execute your javascript.

Example:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                    view.evaluateJavascript("Your JS", null);
                }
            });
```